# Is NFA without null transition allowed?

Tags: nfa

I have made an NFA but have no null transition. is it allowed in NFA? I am creating NFA with generic approach. I am not sure about its correctness. NFA could be any type or is there any particular criteria which should must follow? I had check one website
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238910238_NFAs_With_and_Without_epsilon-Transitions
I didn't sure about without lambda/epsilon NFA is allowed or not

Comment: NFAs do not need to have null transitions. They are optional. NFAs with null transitions, NFAs without null transitions and DFAs are all equivalent to each other in terms of computational power.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks @Welbog